# Convert SQL Inner Join Custom to Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Can I convert my custom SQL syntax into Eloquent Laravel, this is my SQL syntax:

```
SELECT a.* FROM krs a INNER JOIN (
                SELECT kode_matakuliah, MAX(bobot) as bobot_max
                FROM krs
                WHERE nim = 133341043
                GROUP BY kode_matakuliah
            ) b ON a.bobot = b.bobot_max AND a.kode_matakuliah = b.kode_matakuliah 
WHERE nim = 133341043
```

Comment: yes u can, go ahead!

Comment: thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha ! I've find the way.

```
Krs::select(DB::raw('krs.*'))
   ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT kode_matakuliah, MAX(bobot) as bobot_max
       FROM krs
       WHERE nim = 133341043
       GROUP BY kode_matakuliah) as b'),function($join){
       $join->on('krs.kode_matakuliah', '=', 'b.kode_matakuliah')
          ->on('krs.bobot', '=', 'b.bobot_max');
       })
   ->where('krs.no_bukti',1)
   ->where('krs.nim',133341043)->get();
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.6.17 you can use `joinSub()`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23818